# After this "as", are there any words omitted?

Tags: prepositions, conjunctions

> “He is still out there somewhere, perhaps looking for another body to
>   share… not being truly alive, he cannot be killed. He left Quirrell to
>   die; he shows just as little mercy to his followers **as** his
>   enemies.” (Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone)

I’ve been told three ways of seeing ***as***:

1. After ‘as’, ‘*he shows to*’ is omitted,
2. ‘*to*’ is omitted,
3. nothing is omitted.

And now I’m very confused about how to read the *as*. Is ‘as’ a conjunction or a preposition; is there any omission after it or not?

Comment: Why the down vote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Answer amended 09 Aug 2018]

The original wording is, in fact, ambiguous as pointed out in the comments below and in the answer from Kris.

What I would say is that the first two of your suggestions both have the same inherent meaning, which corresponds to the meaning that I originally assumed to have been intended.

The full version would be as followed with *he shows ... to* included twice (repeated words are shown in *italics*:

> *he shows* just as little mercy *to* his followers as *he shows to* his enemies.

but you could omit just *he shows*, with only *to* being repeated and the meaning remains unchanged:

> he shows just as little mercy *to* his followers as *to* his enemies.

If, however, you omit all of *he shows to*, with no repetition (which is the original version):

> he shows just as little mercy to his followers as his enemies.

the sentence becomes ambiguous as pointed out in the answer from Kris.

Comment: Only the last version (with _he shows to_) is ambiguous, however. Another possible interpretation of that is “as his enemies do”, though this is not the correct interpretation in this context.

Comment: The preposition is not positioned for parallelism, and so the structure is not correct.

Comment: @Kris Have amended answer in view of comments and your answer below, which I have up-voted!

Answer (score 0):

"As" either a preposition or a conjunction, the writing leaves something to be desired.  Had she intended "as," "as" I presume, either option (1) or (2) would be preferable to the bare "as."  She could also be meaning to say "as if" his enemies.  But I'm not a billionaire; what do I know?

Comment: “He shows just as little mercy to his followers as if his enemies”? That doesn't make any kind of sense to me.

Answer (score -1):

(2).

However, it's not exactly a question of omission here.  It's almost an incorrect structuring.

"… he shows just as little mercy to his followers as his enemies."

With an assumed preposition omission *to* for **parallelism**,

> … he shows just as little mercy **to** his followers as **to** his enemies.

However, what if it were:

> … he shows just as little mercy to his followers as **do** his enemies.

instead? It's grammatical, makes sense, but means something altogether different.

*meta:*
Answering the question now because in these five years, no one has raised an objection that interpretation/ grammatical critique of literary works is off topic.